# newclude does not include file content

Tags: include

I am trying to include chapters in a document without page breaks and found the `newclude` package can do this using `\include*`, however, when I try to implement it, instead of inputing the file, I just get text.

I have something like this...

```
\input{Layout.tex}  %Here I have some layout stuff for page numbering and such
\input{Macros.tex}  %Here I have the \usepackage{newclude} command
\begin{document}
\input{TitlePage.tex}

\chapter{Introduction}
\include*{1-Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The output is fine through the title page, but the Introduction has the chapter at the top with `Introduction` and the text is `1-Introduction`. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly with this file.

The above compiles fine using the normal `\include` command without the `newclude` package.

Comment: why not simply use `\input` rather than a non standard include mechanism if you do not want to force page breaks, on the other hand in most classes `\chapter` forces a page break anyway so the forced break from include is not a problem.

Comment: Related: [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am trying to do a bibliography after every chapter, including only the entries for that chapter, then a large bibliography at the end including everything. Using \input makes the entire bibliography appear at the end of every chapter.

Answer (score 2):

If the text "1-Introduction" is on a new page, then I think you have forgotten to load the package `newclude`. The original LaTeX definition does not know a star form of `\include`. Then

```
\include*{1-Introduction}
```

does the same as:

```
\include{*}
1-Introduction
```

The star becomes the file name argument for `\include`, likely the file `*.tex` does not exist. This is written to the terminal/`.log` file:

```
No file *.tex.
```

`\include` calls its `\clearpage` and then the text "{1-Introduction}" is set. The curly braces are not used as argument and are executed as simple group
(with no purpose/effect here).

### Summary

The package `newclude` should be loaded:

```
\usepackage{newclude}
```

to get its star form of `\include`.

Comment: You were correct, somehow the "newclude" package wasn't getting loaded. But now I have a different problem. The page break is gone, but now the entire bibliography is at the end of every chapter (and without numbers), so I'm back where I started when using "\input"